# Make an animation in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have an image and need to add an animation for it using pure css.

This is my image looks like:

[image]

So I am looking for an animation to this image is exactly like [this](http://www.orchid-developers.com/oplaza.htm):

I can do it in flash. but I am looking a solution with CSS for better browser support.

Can any CSS expert tell me is there a way to do in CSS?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Make three `<div>`s, position them over the image, give them a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and move them up and down with CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)s.

Comment: @user373381 on **Stackoverflow**, users won't write whole `code` for you, show us what've you tried so far and meanwhile [**visit this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The photo looks like it could be done with an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Xufox had a point in the comments. But if you stuck in how to do it, then you should visit [this](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) page. it is a pure animations library in css and easy to use.